# Gatsby 404 page not working in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-status-code-404, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site deployed on cPanel with a custom 404.js page in the src/pages directory. The 404 page works as expected locally, but in production the user is redirected to / when they land on an invalid url. Gatsby build creates a /404/index.html file and a /404.html file as expected from the documentation. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? I have Gatsby v5.12.11

I've tried gatsby clean before build command, and I've tried using a private browser after every build. I've tried adding a .htaccess file in the file manager with the following code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I've tried adding a gatsby-node.js file at the root of the project with several variations of the following code:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions;

  createRedirect({
    fromPath: `/*`,
    toPath: `/404.html`,
    statusCode: 404,
  });
};
```

Here is my gatsby-config.js file if that makes a difference:

```
/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `test-gatsby`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts`,
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-async`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: "./src/images/",
      },
      __key: "images",
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-omni-font-loader`,
      options: {
        enableListener: true,
        preconnect: [
          `https://fonts.googleapis.com`,
          `https://fonts.gstatic.com`,
        ],
        web: [
          {
            name: `Inter`,
            file: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

And here is my gatsby-browser.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ThemeContext from "./src/contextWrappers/themeContext";
import ScreenSizeContextWrapper from "./src/contextWrappers/screenSizeContext";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
import("./src/styles/global.css");

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <ScreenSizeContextWrapper>
    <ThemeContext>{element}</ThemeContext>
  </ScreenSizeContextWrapper>
);
```

Here is my 404.js file for reference:

```
import Navbar from "../newSrc2/components/navbar/navbar";
import Footer from "../newSrc2/components/footer/newFooter";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import StyledButton from "../newSrc2/components/styledButton/styledButton";
import logoLarge from "../newSrc2/assets/logoLarge.png";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";

const fontStyle = {
  fontFamily: "Inter",
  fontWeight: 600,
  color: "#424245",
  textAlign: "center",
};

function PageNotFound() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Box
        sx={{
          py: { xs: "15vh", lg: "15vh", xl: "20vh" },
          zIndex: -10000000,
        }}
      >
        <Grid
          container
          width={{ xs: "90vw", lg: "80vw", xl: "70vw" }}
          spacing={{ xs: 3, lg: 8 }}
          ml={{ xs: "5vw", lg: "10vw", xl: "15vw" }}
        >
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={6} textAlign="center" my="auto">
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              sx={{ ...fontStyle, mb: { xs: 3, lg: 2, xl: 4 } }}
            >
              Sorry!
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="h4"
              sx={{
                ...fontStyle,
                m: "0 auto",
                width: "100%",
                maxWidth: "450px",
              }}
            >
              We can’t seem to find the page you’re looking for.
            </Typography>
            <StyledButton
              sx={{
                bgcolor: "black",
                fontFamily: "Inter",
                borderRadius: "30px",
                width: "200px",
                color: "white",
                mt: { xs: 4, lg: 5, xl: 6 },
              }}
              onClick={() => navigate("/")}
              variant="contained"
            >
              take me home
            </StyledButton>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={6} my="auto">
            <img src={logoLarge} style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default PageNotFound;
```

I've scoured SO and nothing anyone suggests seems to work, please help!!